# Hide installed programs on windows

Tags: windows, security

How can I hide installed programs from being seen in control panel on windows?

The easiest way of doing this is using some programs like :[Hide Program](http://www.download3k.com/Security/Other-Utilities/Download-Hide-Programs.html)

But the download link of this program doesn't valid anymore.

And I also know this can be done by modifying registry. But if want them to be seen again, this is really lots of work to do.

What's your ideas?

Comment: your only trying to stop the casual observer correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, modifying the registry is not that complicated.
In [this](http://www.computeronlinetips.com/registry-tips/hide-Control-Panel-icons.html) link you'll fine an easy step-by-step guide, that will guide you through these steps.

If it still doesn't feet you, here you'll find a working link for the [Hide Program](http://www.download3000.com/download_23551.html) software.

Comment: Sorry, but your first link is broken or down. Please update it.

Comment: The link in 'this' doesn't work.